# CodeIgniter, Know the controller which called function

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I am trying to create library that will write "error" messages in `database`, I do not think that I will be able to write `PHPs` errors <strike>nor `CodeIgniters`</strike>, but I can write my own "errors" something like

`$this->error->write("User is not allowed to go in here");`

I know there is a [error handling](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html) already built in `CodeIgniter` on top of all it only supports writing `errors/infos/debugs` in **file** not database.

*The real question is:* how to get `controller` that called function.

Lets say I am in controller -> `./admin/settings.php` and error ocures, code will call my library and I want it to store controller that called it. (I may be forced to send it as parameter but I don't want to write manually that it was `fcn("error text", "/settings.php");`

Assumed output: `/controllers/admin/settings.php` somewhere inside `class` that is called by controller.

Comment: I also found this one `$this->router->fetch_class();`, what I am trying to achieve is simple just send one parameter to function not two. I am going to try `__FILE__` but I am afraid that it will return `index.php` well, lets see.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the router class to get this info

Also works with `Codeigniter v3.0.x`

To get the controller(class)

```
$this->router->class
```

To get the method(function)

```
$this->router->method
```